How do I programmatically check if a Flatpak package is installed in a shell script?
I'm writing a script where I want to detect whether a given Flatpak package is installed, and take a different code path depending on the answer. How can I accomplish this? Traditional measures like command -v obviously won't work unless the user manually has taken the necessary steps to add Flatpak packages to $PATH, so I don't want to rely on that.

Just ask flatpak for info on the package, suppress all output and check the return value:
appid=com.play0ad.zeroad

flatpak info "${appid}" >/dev/null 2>&1 && do_what_you_want_here

